# Embed \cite in \bibnote

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{notes2bib}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\defbibnote{intro}{This intro works perfectly well.}

\begin{document}

In this essay, I will disclose rhetorical strategies invented by John Doe \bibnote{The author cites from \cite{somekey} only in the 1984 edition.}. However, in the Notes at the end, it does not look exactly the way I would like it \bibnote{\ldots but this does!}.

\printbibliography[title=Notes, prenote=intro]

\end{document}
```

For completeness here is the BibTeX entry (could be anything really):

```
@ARTICLE{somekey,
  author = {Dunno, Someone I.},
  title = {Whatever Works},
  journal = {Paper Series},
  year = {2069},
  volume = {XXX},
  pages = {69--96}
}
```

The result is:

[image: Bothersome result...]

What really bothers me is that instead of printing the actual bibliographic entry in the Notes, another entry `[3]` is created (at the end of the bibliography on top of that!)... How can I have something like:

> [1] The author cites from Someone I. Dunno. "Whatever Works". In: Paper Series XXX (2069), pp. 69--96. only in the 1984 edition.

The problem is that I have a different text snippet before and after each citation (or sometimes no text at all).

**NOTE**: I tried to wrap `\cite` in `\bibnote` because I am using `\bibnote`s anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you  want the full citation in the note? If so a workaround would be use `\fullcite` instead of `\cite` inside `\bibnote`, and to add the citations cite with `\fullcite` to a category to be excluded in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{somekey,
  author = {Dunno, Someone I.},
  title = {Whatever Works},
  journal = {Paper Series},
  year = {2069},
  volume = {XXX},
  pages = {69--96}
}  
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\defbibnote{intro}{This intro works perfectly well.}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{fullcited}

\begin{document}

In this essay, I will disclose rhetorical strategies invented by John Doe \bibnote{The author cites from \fullcite{somekey}\addtocategory{fullcited}{somekey} only in the 1984 edition.}. However, in the Notes at the end, it does not look exactly the way I would like it \bibnote{\ldots but this does!}.

\printbibliography[title=Notes, prenote=intro, notcategory=fullcited]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Just what I need! `:)`