# How can I have a reverse order in the bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

I want to have the bookmarks in my TeX output, pdf file, such that they are inversed.

Like this:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

   \begin{document}

   \tableofcontents

   \section{Hello}‎
   \section{Wow}
   \section{Bye}

   \tableofcontents

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Starting from the last entry on the top? And the title page at the very end? Or do you want to have the page number in front of the line and the title at the end of the line? What is clear to you, is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: As the first sentence you wrote.  'the last entry on the top'

Comment: Can you show a minimal working example? A possible solution depends on the class and toc changing packages if used.

Comment: You can plan a tex with arbitrary sections and show me how can I have revserved table in my output!

Comment: Do please add some complete minimal document with expected output.

Comment: Will wonders never cease. How about hierarchical levels? Is the TOC line for subsection 5.4.6 to precede those for chapter 5 and section 5.4?

Comment: I added some details. @Johannes_B

Comment: I added some details. @jfbu

Comment: @MyGlasses Now I am really confused. Do you want the reverse order in the table of contents or in the bookmarks?

Comment: I added some details. @MichaelPalmer

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, In bookmark. It was my fault!

Answer (score 4):

Well, update to OP's indicates what is wanted is reversed ordered in the *bookmarks*. But bookmarks require hyperref, and the posted mwe does not use `hyperref` and the posted image does not show actual TOC of document.

Thus I am afraid I got started on this on wrong premises. Anyway, here is, adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171556/4686 how to achieve this **for the LaTeX generated TOC of the document**. It is with or without `hyperref`, but bookmarks are not modified.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newtoks\mytoks
\makeatletter

\@ifundefined{hyperref}
{\mytoks{\def\contentsline #1#2#3{%
         \def\x{\contentsline {#1}{#2}{#3}}%
         \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter 
                {\expandafter\x\the\toks@}%
 }}}%
{\mytoks{\def\contentsline #1#2#3#4{%
         \def\x{\contentsline {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
         \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter 
                {\expandafter\x\the\toks@}%
 }}}%

\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\toks@{}%
                    \string\the\string\mytoks}% extra \string for space token finicking
\AtEndDocument 
  {\addtocontents {toc}{\string\expandafter\string\endgroup\string\the\string\toks@}}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\section{A}

\subsection{A.1}

\section{B}

\subsection{B.1}

\section{C}

\subsection{C.1}

\section{D}

\subsection{D.1}

Hello there.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding subsections pretty much ruins the look of the TOC, but with only sections it would be fine.

Comment: thanks for your work. this post wasn't refresh to now. I see your answer after 45mins.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go. This time we handle the bookmarks but leave the TOC untouched.

CAVEAT: the code is for a document with article class with sections but not parts. It is QUITE HACKY. NOT TESTED WITH PACKAGE `bookmark` ONLY WITH PACKAGE `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\let\original@write\write

\def\write #1{\write@zzz#1\@outlinefile\@nil}

\def\write@zzz #1\@outlinefile#2\@nil
             {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
              \expandafter\@firstoftwo
              \else
              \expandafter\@secondoftwo
              \fi {\noexpand\hacked@write@tooutline}{\original@write#1}}

\newtoks\mytoksA
\newtoks\mytoksB

\def\hacked@write@tooutline #1%
   {\gdef\hacked@tmp{#1^^J}\hacked@write #1\hacked@write}

\def\hacked@write #1[#2]#3\hacked@write{%
    \ifnum #2=1
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\global\mytoksA\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\expandafter\the\expandafter\mytoksB\the\mytoksA}%  
     \global\mytoksB\expandafter{\hacked@tmp}}%
    {\global\mytoksB\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            {\expandafter\the\expandafter\mytoksB\hacked@tmp}}%
}%

\makeatletter

\tableofcontents

\section{A}

\subsection{A.1}

in first subsection of first section

\subsection{A.2}

in second subsection of first section

\section{B}

\subsection{B.1}

in first subsection of second section

\subsection{B.2}

in second subsection of second section

\section{C}

\subsection{C.1}

\subsection{C.2}

\section{D}

\subsection{D.1}

\subsection{D.2}

Hello there.

\makeatletter

\immediate\original@write\@outlinefile{\the\mytoksB\the\mytoksA}

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this view I am not sure I understand the Skim colouring of bookmarks but they are functional.

Comment: I should have insisted perhaps that the mwe has some important tidbit right before `\end{document}` that line must not be forgotten for the thing to work.

Comment: the thing is done in order to reverse the order of sections but within each section to keep subsections (and deeper stuff) in correct order. If the document contains parts, they will get out of sync with sections. This is all controlled by the `\ifnum#2=1 ` line.