# Why aren't my keywords recognized when immediately followed by a comma?

Tags: listings, bold, comma-separated-list, keywords

I am using `listings` to display custom keywords in bold. In my listings, those keywords are sometimes followed by a comma. However, in the example below, any comma following a keyword will prevent the keyword from being recognized.

[image: Rendering of the code below]

How can I make `listings` recognize `CustomKeyword` and `if` as keywords, even when they're immdiately followed by a comma ?

```
\usepackage{lstlistings}

\lstdefinelanguage{csharp}{
  alsoletter={@,=,>,},
  morekeywords={return, if, is, int, CustomKeyword, else, or, bool},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]"
}

\lstset{
  language=csharp,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=spaceflexible,%fullflexible,
  mathescape=true,
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  basicstyle=\codestyle
} 

\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible]
CustomKeyword  // OK in bold.
CustomKeyword, // Not in bold anymore.
if //OK in bold
if, // Not in bold anymore
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean "comma", but just in case you really did want your code to have a "coma", we have answers for that at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122116/how-to-prolong-compilation-time-while-engaging-in-leisure-activities.  I am just having fun, of course.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Please turn your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Write `alsoletter=@=>,` instead of `alsoletter={@,=,>,},`; the latter defines `,` as a "letter", which means that `listings` treats it as a valid character in identifiers and keywords.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out @StevenB.Segletes now corrected

Comment: Corrected spelling will help for future searches of the topic.

Comment: @Jubobs your solution works. Please post it so that it will help people looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problematic line is

```
alsoletter={@,=,>,},
```

You shouldn't use commas to delimit the characters you want to declare as "letters". If you do, `listings` takes those commas *literally* and declares the comma itself as a "letter"; as a result, `listings` treats `if,` as an identifier distinct from `if`.

Correct `alsoletter` syntaxes include

```
alsoletter={@=>},
```

and even (much less readable!)

```
alsoletter=@=>,
```

(Note that the comma at the end of that line is simply interpreted as a delimiter for `listings` key-value pairs, not as a character declared as "letter".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{csharp}{
  alsoletter={@=>},
  morekeywords={return, if, is, int, CustomKeyword, else, or, bool},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
}

\lstset{
  language=csharp,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=spaceflexible,%fullflexible,
  mathescape=true,
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible]
CustomKeyword  // OK in bold.
CustomKeyword, // in bold too :)
if //OK in bold
if, // in bold too
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```