# VERY slow compile time

Tags: compiling

I am new to Latex, using it for engineering reports. The compilation of a document of mine, including 4 pages and 5-7 figures, takes about 2 minutes, on a DELL Inspiron i5 and 2.2 GHZ laptop. However, my friend's laptop, which is much older, does the same task in only a few seconds. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The exact same file? Are the figures simply 'included' or are they being processed, too, each time you compile? Have you tried compiling from the command line and watching to see where the bottleneck(s) is/are? Are you using `lualatex`? Are you using `microtype`? Is someone playing a [trick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122116/8528) on you? Without any code, the questions are endless....

Comment: What kind of code would you like to see? I use \begin{figure} \includegraphics[] for my .png files. I am very new to this so I am not sure what compiling from command line is or does. I use the "build" button on the top. I am using Texniccenter

Comment: On windows? Open a [command prompt in the folder where the `.tex` file is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/378319/1075876) and try to compile it with the command `pdflatex myfile.tex` (where 'myfile.tex' is the name of your project; please rename it so there are no spaces in the name just to make our lives easier). Make a note of the page numbers, which are marked so: `[1]` (= page 1). If it slows down after you see `[2]`, then the bottleneck may be on page 3.

Comment: it seems to slow down when it reached the .png files. Tookk about 1min 10 sec for the whole thing to run. I noticed that it always took very long on .png files, but I have to include pictures in my report. Any advice on that?

Comment: Converting the pictures to pdf outside latex and including those new files might speed things up.  I assume the files are stored locally on your machine, not on a network share.

Comment: How large are the png files?

Comment: What is the size of .png files?

Comment: Yes, they are saved to my desktop and not a cloud or network share. The smallest is about 97KB and the biggest goes to about 20,000KB. Is there any program on Windows 10 that will convert to PDF to speed up compile time or should I just do it online? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem (please see my post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382885/graphics-rich-tex-file-takes-a-long-time-to-compile-in-texmaker) Were you able to solve this problem? Was the suggestion to convert image files to pdf by @Chris H useful?

Comment: Ok, it's an old post. However, the method I lined out here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603835/how-to-resolve-extra-or-forgotten-in-multline/603850#603850 will work as well to narrow down the problem(s). E.g. in this specific case you'd like to get a feel for your computer-(La)Tex system for text-only, graphics only etc. Perhaps even certain packages impose some extra time. Perhaps order of things is an issue. Etc.