# Math mode not working

Tags: miktex

when ever I'm trying to use math mode in the beamer there is this error

> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
>
> Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
> miktex-makepk: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has
> checked for updates.
>
> Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `slp-idp-2.out' has changed. (rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right (rerunfilecheck)                or use package` bookmark'.
>
> ) (see the transcript file for additional information) !pdfTeX error:
> pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 600 not f ound
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! pdflatex: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
>
> C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log texify:
> major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.

Comment: Well as the error says: check for updates in admin mode. And then run in the miktex console (user mode) the task to update the font map files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest locating the troublemaker by stepwise exclusion and inclusion.

See my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603850/245790 .

I.e. remove as much as is needed to make MiKTeX pass. Then start adding your math staff. Or in reverse start with your current version and delete one half of it (make a reasonable choice about what "half" should mean). Zoom in on the problem.

If it's in your code, like a typo or a false syntax, you'll find it this way. It it's a matter related to the preamble, you end up with some rudimentary code, which should work for sure, but doesn't ... THAT's the hint you needed.

Good luck :)