# A colored pattern but a little change to the random function in TikZ is required

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, fun, pattern

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{elila}{RGB}{186,85,211}
\definecolor{zlila}{RGB}{138,43,226}

\definecolor{dblau}{RGB}{30,144,255}
\definecolor{sblau}{RGB}{106,90,205}

\definecolor{brot}{RGB}{178,34,34}
\definecolor{mrot}{RGB}{128,0,0}
\definecolor{pgruen}{RGB}{152,251,152}
\definecolor{mgruen}{RGB}{60,179,113}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\random{int(random(1,3))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\rangle{\random*90}
            \ifnum\random=1
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate around={(\rangle:(.5,.5))}]
                    \fill[brot] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                    \fill[mrot] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},mrot] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]-135:.25) arc(-135:-135+180:.25);
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},brot] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]45:.25) arc(45:45+180:.25);
            \fi
            \ifnum\random=2
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate around={(\rangle:(.5,.5))}]
                    \fill[pgruen] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                    \fill[mgruen] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},mgruen] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]-135+90:.25) arc(-135+90:-135+90+180:.25);
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},pgruen] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]45+90:.25) arc(45+90:45+90+180:.25);
            \fi
            \ifnum\random=3
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate around={(\rangle:(.5,.5))}]
                    \fill[elila] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                    \fill[zlila] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},elila] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]-135:.25) arc(-135:-135+180:.25);
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},zlila] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]45:.25) arc(45:45+180:.25);
            \fi
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output (the look of the pattern depends on the system time):

[image: Screenshot]

My questions is: How can I achieve that I get for every second (range: 10 seconds) a seperate "frame" this pattern? Because for the random pattern the system time is used and there are changes in every minute but it is still the same "frame".

I want to get, when I convert the `.pdf` file into a `.gif`, an animation.

Comment: Add a loop that does nothing but taking time. Of course the loop should emd at some point. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122116/how-to-prolong-compilation-time-while-engaging-in-leisure-activities

Comment: `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be happy to remove this (on the other hand it looks nice ;-).

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{elila}{RGB}{186,85,211}
\definecolor{zlila}{RGB}{138,43,226}

\definecolor{dblau}{RGB}{30,144,255}
\definecolor{sblau}{RGB}{106,90,205}

\definecolor{brot}{RGB}{178,34,34}
\definecolor{mrot}{RGB}{128,0,0}
\definecolor{pgruen}{RGB}{152,251,152}
\definecolor{mgruen}{RGB}{60,179,113}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,42}
{    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\X}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,5}
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\random{int(random(1,3))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\rangle{\random*90}
            \ifnum\random=1
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate around={(\rangle:(.5,.5))}]
                    \fill[brot] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                    \fill[mrot] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},mrot] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]-135:.25) arc(-135:-135+180:.25);
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},brot] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]45:.25) arc(45:45+180:.25);
            \fi
            \ifnum\random=2
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate around={(\rangle:(.5,.5))}]
                    \fill[pgruen] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                    \fill[mgruen] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},mgruen] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]-135+90:.25) arc(-135+90:-135+90+180:.25);
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},pgruen] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]45+90:.25) arc(45+90:45+90+180:.25);
            \fi
            \ifnum\random=3
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate around={(\rangle:(.5,.5))}]
                    \fill[elila] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                    \fill[zlila] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
                \end{scope}
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},elila] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]-135:.25) arc(-135:-135+180:.25);
                \fill[shift={(\x,\y)},zlila] ([shift={(.5,.5)}]45:.25) arc(45:45+180:.25);
            \fi
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]